# How to get ownership of smart contract using web3 Api Python?

Tags: python, smartcontracts, web3py

I am practicing with web3 APIs and Python. I would like to extract the ownership of a specific smart contract giving the contract address (or smart contract) as input and getting as output the ownership of the contract.

For example if I check this contract `0x2A9718defF471f3Bb91FA0ECEAB14154F150a385` [on BscScan](https://bscscan.com/token/0x2A9718defF471f3Bb91FA0ECEAB14154F150a385#readContract) reading the contract on point n.11 I can see the ownership is owned by this address `0x42997cf4fc165ebb8269cffc54a3198984367f02`. How to automatize this process with web3 APIs on python? Or do you know any other method to get it except of selenium webdriver?

Comment: first you should check in documentation if it has this functionality. Some APIs may gives only part of data and rest may need to pay for it - or you have to use `Selenium` to get it without paying.

Answer (score 1):

I don't using web3 and bitcoin, but I
found a similar question on the [Ethereum Stack Exchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/22859/how-to-get-value-of-a-contract-public-property-using-web3-eth) site written in JavaScript.

Digging into Python examples on the internet, I created a version in Python:

```py
from web3 import Web3

bsc = "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc))

print("connected:", web3.isConnected())

abi = '''[
    {
      "constant": true,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "owner",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "address"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "constructor"
    }
]'''

contract = web3.eth.contract(address="0x2A9718defF471f3Bb91FA0ECEAB14154F150a385", abi=abi)
owner = contract.functions.owner().call()

print("owner:", owner)
```

And this gives me `0x42997cf4fc165ebb8269cffc54a3198984367f02`

Comment: Your solution works well. Thank you. How to change 'bsc' variable if I want to get the contract owner on ethereum mainnet? thank you.

Comment: I didn't test it but see quick example in documentation: [Provider: Infura](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#provider-infura). It uses https://mainnet.infura.io/

Comment: I tried your url and it gives me `InsufficientDataBytes: Tried to read 32 bytes.  Only got 0 bytes`. Maybe it needs different text in `abi`

Comment: How could I solve this problem? Should do another question? Or need to ask for python-version on question you mentioned before? thank you a lot for your helping.

Comment: I don't know how to resolve it - I never used `web3` and `Contract`. As for me problem is `abi` which may depends on `mainnet` documentation - different servers may need different `abi`. It has nothing to do with Python. But you could create it as new question - you will have more space to add minimal working code and description.

Comment: Hi @giacomomaraglino I trully advise you to remove your comment containing your `API` key.